# Efficient way to filter a Map by value in Elixir

Tags: dictionary, filter, elixir

In Elixir, what would be an efficient way to filter a `Map` by its values.

Right now I have the following solution

```
%{foo: "bar", biz: nil, baz: 4}
|> Enum.reject(fn {_, v} -> is_nil(v) end)
|> Map.new
```

This solution seems pretty inefficient to me. When called on a `Map`, `Enum.reject/2` returns a `Keywords`. Since I want a `Map`, I need to call `Map.new/1` to convert that `Keywords` back to me.

This seems inefficient because `Enum.reject/2` has to iterate over the `Map` once and then presumably, `Map.new/1` has to iterate over the `Keywords` another time.

What would be a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `:maps.filter/2`, which filters a map and does not create any intermediate list:

```
iex(1)> :maps.filter fn _, v -> v != nil end, %{foo: "bar", biz: nil, baz: 4}
%{baz: 4, foo: "bar"}
```

A simple benchmark confirms this is faster than `Enum.filter` + `Map.new`:

```
map = for i <- 1..100000, into: %{}, do: {i, Enum.random([nil, 1, 2])}

IO.inspect :timer.tc(fn ->
  map
  |> Enum.reject(fn {_, v} -> is_nil(v) end)
  |> Map.new
end)

IO.inspect :timer.tc(fn ->
  :maps.filter fn _, v -> v != nil end, map
end)
```

```
{44728,
 %{48585 => 1, 60829 => 2, 12995 => 1, 462 => 2, 704 => 2, 28954 => 2,
   29635 => 2, 78798 => 1, 92572 => 1, 89750 => 2, 39389 => 2, 62855 => 2,
   79313 => 1, 92062 => 2, 61871 => 1, 92856 => 2, 75920 => 1, 59922 => 1,
   37912 => 2, 30420 => 2, 51211 => 2, 7994 => 2, 78269 => 2, 9765 => 2,
   38352 => 2, 6653 => 1, 82555 => 2, 54031 => 2, 45138 => 1, 41351 => 1,
   40746 => 1, 5961 => 1, 66704 => 2, 33823 => 1, 47603 => 1, 86873 => 1,
   81009 => 2, 96255 => 1, 36219 => 1, 1328 => 2, 33314 => 1, 54477 => 2,
   40189 => 2, 27028 => 1, 31676 => 1, 94037 => 1, 32388 => 1, 4351 => 1,
   46309 => 1, ...}}
{28638,
 %{48585 => 1, 60829 => 2, 12995 => 1, 462 => 2, 704 => 2, 28954 => 2,
   29635 => 2, 78798 => 1, 92572 => 1, 89750 => 2, 39389 => 2, 62855 => 2,
   79313 => 1, 92062 => 2, 61871 => 1, 92856 => 2, 75920 => 1, 59922 => 1,
   37912 => 2, 30420 => 2, 51211 => 2, 7994 => 2, 78269 => 2, 9765 => 2,
   38352 => 2, 6653 => 1, 82555 => 2, 54031 => 2, 45138 => 1, 41351 => 1,
   40746 => 1, 5961 => 1, 66704 => 2, 33823 => 1, 47603 => 1, 86873 => 1,
   81009 => 2, 96255 => 1, 36219 => 1, 1328 => 2, 33314 => 1, 54477 => 2,
   40189 => 2, 27028 => 1, 31676 => 1, 94037 => 1, 32388 => 1, 4351 => 1,
   46309 => 1, ...}}
```

Comment: in case anyone wonders, `:maps.filter` is http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#filter-2

Answer (score 3):

In this case comprehension would be a good idea, because it also does not create an intermediate list and returns you a map:

```
map = %{baz: 4, biz: nil, foo: "bar"}
for {key, value} <- map, !is_nil(value), into: %{}, do: {key, value}
```

Comment: This should not create an intermediate list, but in practice, I've found `for ..., into: %{}` to be even slower than creating a list with `Enum.filter/2` and passing it to `Map.new/1`. I tried it with the benchmark I posted in my answer and this runs slower than OP's code by about 20-25% for me.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not surprised that erlang's solution is the fastest one.

Answer (score 2):

Since Elixir version 1.13, `Map.filter(map, fun)` exists natively. See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#filter/2

Answer (score 0):

It could be a little expensive but it is more declarative, which IMO adds more value.
Also consider how big is going to be your collection and if it makes sense to optimize this filter.

However, I understand your concern, so here is what I did:

```
%{foo: "bar", biz: nil, baz: 4}
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, filter_nil_values/2)
```

Where `filter_nil_values/2` is defined as

```
defp filter_nil_values({_k, nil}, accum), do: accum
defp filter_nil_values({k, v}, accum), do: Map.put(accum, k, v)
```

I tried to do this in a one-line function, but it looks awful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write like this:

```
m = %{foo: "bar", biz: nil, baz: 4}

Enum.reduce(m, m, fn 
  {key, nil}, acc -> Map.delete(acc, key)
  {_, _}, acc -> acc
end)
```

The code above is quite efficient if there are few `nil` values in `m`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map.filter(%{foo: "bar", biz: nil, baz: 4}, 
                         fn {_, v} -> v != nil end)
```