# Enum.filter change type from dict to ordered dict

Tags: dictionary, filter, elixir, ordereddictionary

I run following code:

```
iex(1)> %{a: 1, b: nil} |> Enum.filter(fn {_key, value} -> !is_nil(value) end)      
[a: 1]
```

But I expect to see `%{a: 1}` What kind of concept is behind this? How can I get the same but with expected type?

Comment: Dup? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44148961/3507061

Comment: Also: `for {_, v} = kv when not is_nil(v) <- %{a: 1, b: nil}, into: %{}, do: kv`.

Comment: Also: `Enum.reduce(%{a: 1, b: nil}, %{}, fn {_, nil}, acc -> acc; {k, v}, acc -> Map.put(acc, k, v) end)`.