# Elixir filter map entries by a conditional

Tags: dictionary, filter, elixir

I have a Map in Elixir which maps from string keys to a value which is a list of attributes. How can I remove the items which do not meet the criteria as I enumerate through the Map?

The map looks like this:

```
%{"A" => [needed: true], "B" => [needed: false]}
```

In this case I would check each key/value pair and only keep the ones with needed: true

I have tried doing different combinations of using Enum.map and Enum.each so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you need to filter values out of an enumerable like a Map, [Enum.filter/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) is your friend. The trick is that you need to sort of "reassemble" the result back into a map.

```
%{"A" => [needed: true], "B" => [needed: false]}
|> Enum.filter(fn {_, v} -> Keyword.get(v, :needed) end)
|> Enum.into(%{})

# Result:
%{"A" => [needed: true]}
```

Comment: I would do `Map.new()` instead of `Enum.into(%{})`, and it's faster too, I believe.

Comment: Ah, it seems `Enum.into` was improved in June this year, so they may be doing the same thing under the hood now anyway: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/d9a81101ddd33b8ed4b6e6386f91555cdcb77662#diff-9a538f965f1fdc2cf9780b1008560f05bfa2ff80d145445abe37a0d70d3828a2

Answer (score 2):

This is not very idiomatic Elixir, but as Dogbert [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44148961/1225617), it's also possible to do this directly with [`:maps.filter/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#filter-2), avoiding the intermediate list:

```
iex(2)> :maps.filter(fn _, v -> Keyword.get(v, :needed) end, map)
%{"A" => [needed: true]}
```